# Передача цвета пропсом styled.component и next.js

Tags: styled-components

Есть задача:

1. сверстать несколько похожих компонентов(cкрин прикладываю)
2. использовать styled.components.

Мне кажется это можно сделать проще чем это сделано у меня.

Я на базе одного контейнера делаю другие где меняю цвет, но это получаются разные компоненты. Думаю сделать чтобы компонент был один но как то передать пропсом цвет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
export default function Box({ title, description, children }) {
  const Container = styled.div`
    width: 290px;
    height: 109px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  `;

  const BlueContainer = styled(Container)`
    background: linear-gradient(199.15deg, #334ffe 7.38%, #6c2feb 95.63%);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px rgba(90, 49, 100, 0.226972);
  `;

  const MagentaContainer = styled(Container)`
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #b00cc8 0%, #600398 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px rgba(90, 49, 100, 0.226972);
  `;

  const CyanContainer = styled(Container)`
    background: linear-gradient(187.95deg, #1ac9b7 10.29%, #4da8ee 90.89%);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px rgba(90, 49, 100, 0.226972);
  `;

  const Title = styled.h1`
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
  `;
  const Description = styled.p`
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  `;

  const InfoWrap = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    max-width: 205px;
  `;

  return (
    <>
      <BlueContainer>
        <InfoWrap>
          <Title>{title}</Title>
          <Description>{description}</Description>
        </InfoWrap>
        <BtnBoxNext />
      </BlueContainer>
      <MagentaContainer>
        <Title>Абакус</Title>
        <Description>Потренируй свой навык ментальной арифметики.</Description>
      </MagentaContainer>
      <CyanContainer>
        <Description>Приведи друга и получи урок в подарок </Description>
      </CyanContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: 1) при чем Здесь __nextjs__ 2) сформулируй вопрос в своём вопросе

Comment: Nextjs не причём сказал какую технологию использую.  Есть похожие элементы приложения. Разный фон а контент внутри одинаковый. Я решаю этот вопрос создавая на базе одного из этих компонентов другие и задаю им нужный цвет. Я думаю что проще было бы сделать один компонент и с помощью пропсов как то менять их цвет. Как это сделать не разобрался ещё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Песочница

[там: typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8DOAXAnhEwBc8UAdpgNwBQoksCyM8ASiFGOgVgA4gD2AZvAEsAth24x0ACgDkcFuikBKClWhwkKJnIAiAeQCy7TFz6CRYyTOasAtMG5DFFAPRP41gDTXyLt5-LkwbiIMeABzECIAYW54AF54CUCIMTj4KVC4CMU4gD40LBxgADpgAUQAA3J4avgksQIAEgBvOpgAXwpKnw8vAKCQ6KJ0EAEiEHp48KjuCQU%204PR4QeHR8YAhAFcIDYRJiOjpACNtkEV5gaCVsZgmYFSpg8tgM%209XHtffXsCF%20ABVIjKUHGqCgEFSGGwuBKZUqNVq3GSMEaTQkLQRKXi6UyRCkbQUuXhiI65C6bz83T8-nImlYuj0RTgRFAMAkAB4cuRWcsRtcOXDuasYJynALeZyABb0JwcrmXHnrLY7Pk1UUKk7C1UwTYnGWS%20DSzma27K6pG3AauWC40SqW622c-6A4Gg%20Acx3IZ0QYXuoEwEEQO36mU%20z2EsSxABEcGAEY50e9AI9ftBgYNrJDybBrUjxx2sfIuZACadmZl0vc8DsYA2Qgi6CKh24wEwcyAA)

### Запустить можно здесь

```js
"use strict";
// -,-
// -,-
const genCo = (color = 'green') => styled.div `
    color: ${color};
`;
// -,-
const Conteiner = genCo();
const ConteinerBulue = genCo('blue');
const ConteinerRed = genCo('red');
// -,-
// -,-
const Univaersal = styled.div `
    color: ${({ color = 'green' }) => color};
`;
// -,-
// -,-
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(React.Fragment, null,
    React.createElement(Conteiner, null, "Conteiner"),
    React.createElement("hr", null),
    React.createElement(ConteinerBulue, null, "ConteinerBulue"),
    React.createElement("hr", null),
    React.createElement(ConteinerRed, null, "ConteinerRed"),
    React.createElement("hr", null),
    React.createElement("hr", null),
    React.createElement(Univaersal, null, "Univaersal"),
    React.createElement("hr", null),
    React.createElement(Univaersal, { color: "red" }, "red"),
    React.createElement("hr", null),
    React.createElement(Univaersal, { color: "blue" }, "blue")), document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components@4.0.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
```

### Доки

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props